# Spoof Windows MACs without restriction

Tags: windows, mac-address, mac-spoofing

How do I spoof the MAC address in Windows without `02` or `00` being the first octal? Microsoft has restricted it to 02 and 00 being the first octal!

The MAC Spoofing works perfectly when I am on Linux distros. I tried searching the internet but couldn't find anything. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search gave me this explanation.

> Setting first octet "02" actually sets the b2 bit indicating that the
>   MAC address is locally administered. Looking at this MAC address thus
>   indicates that the MAC address is changed by local machine
>   administrator. But, its still good if you just want to hide your
>   original MAC address instead of spoofing someone's MAC address.
>
> Another guess on why this works may be due to Windows Network Bridge
>   feature. When you bridge 2 or more network adapters in Windows, the
>   Network Bridge sets its MAC address to the first network adapter added
>   to it with the first octet set to "02". Thus, if the network adapter
>   drivers didn't allow the change, it would make the feature not work.

Source: [TMAC Issue With Wireless Network & Workaround](http://blog.technitium.com/2011/05/tmac-issue-with-wireless-network.html)

So, I guess your best bet would be to use any Linux distro on VMware or VirtualBox and change your mac in that to whatever you want. Linux has no such limitation. :)

Comment: I want some workaround to work on windows, if possible. I read this on the internet before